# MacBook Pro 2012 Disk Upgrade

Tags: ssd, hard-disk, macbook

I have an old MacBook Pro 2012 that I would quite like to resurrect, however it is INTENSELY SLOW, even after a reinstall of MacOS High Sierra. It has 16GB RAM and a Core i7, so I can't see those being a problem...
Does anyone have a good recommendation for an SSD drive to put in the MacBook? Preferably larger than the 240GB disk it came with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mid 2012 or Retina? For the Mid, anything that fits - 2.5" SATA [you can even get a caddy to put a 2nd in place of the DVD drive].

The Retina is more complicated [& not one I've ever had apart] See https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/macbook-pro-retina-display-faq/macbook-pro-retina-display-how-to-upgrade-ssd-storage.html

Comment: It's just a Mid-2012, but thanks for the link anyway